How can I propagate pointer event from the child ClickableText to a parent composable?
I'm facing the issue that when I have a composable that has ClickableText in it, I can't detect the pointer event like click, long press, etc in the parent composable.
The example is below. In this example, I don't get onLongClick and onClick called while onClick of the ClickableText is called. I want the operations in event handlers on the parent composable to be executed only when the getStringAnnotations returns nothing (which means a user clicked any place other than URL text).
I guess I have to add a custom gesture by the .pointerInput modifier but I don't understand how to realize it. Or any other better solutions?
@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@DevicePreviews
@Composable
fun Preview() {
    val text = remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    val annotatedString = annotatedString("Hello, https://google.com world!")
    Column(modifier = Modifier
        .combinedClickable(onLongClick = {
            text.value = "Long clicked parent"
        }, onClick = {
            text.value = "Clicked parent"
        })
    ) {
        Text(text.value)
        ClickableText(text = annotatedString) { offset ->
            annotatedString.getStringAnnotations(tag = "URL", start = offset, end = offset)
                .firstOrNull()?.let {
                    text.value = "Clicked child"
                }
        }
    }
}

fun annotatedString(text: String): AnnotatedString = buildAnnotatedString {
    val urlRegex = "(https?://[\\w\\-._~:/?#\\[\\]@!$&'()*+,;=]+)".toRegex()
    val matches = urlRegex.findAll(text)

    var lastIndex = 0
    for (match in matches) {
        withStyle(style = SpanStyle(color = Color.Black)) {
            append(text.substring(lastIndex, match.range.first))
        }
        pushStringAnnotation(tag = "URL", annotation = match.value)
        withStyle(
            style = SpanStyle(
                color = Color.Blue,
                textDecoration = TextDecoration.Underline,
                fontSize = 16.sp
            )
        ) {
            append(match.value)
        }
        pop()
        lastIndex = match.range.last + 1
    }
    withStyle(style = SpanStyle(color = Color.Black)) {
        append(text.substring(lastIndex, text.length))
    }
}


What is it that you are trying to achieve? Do you want to differentiate between clicking actual link - google.com and normal text - hello world?

@ChanMyaeAung Not only that but also I'd like to get the event handlers e.g. long click handler on the parent composable executed.
